# How to properly use Nullable w/ numeric types in constructors?

Tags: vb.net, nullable

In VB.NET, I have a class that implements a range of numbers, call it `NumericRange(Of T)`.  Internally, `NumericRange` stores `T` as a Nullable, `T?`.  I have another class that wraps this class as `NumericRange(Of UInt16)`.  Call this class `MyNumRange` (I'm being simplistic here).

So In `MyNumRange`, I have a few constructors defined:

```
Public Sub New(ByVal num1 As UInt16?, ByVal num2 As UInt16?)
    ' Code
End Sub

Public Sub New(ByVal num As UInt16, ByVal flag As Boolean)
    ' Code
End Sub

Public Sub New(ByVal num As UInt16)
    ' Code
End Sub
```

In some code outside of `MyNumRange`, I try to instantiate an open-ended range.  That is, a range value where one of the operands is missing to represent a greater-than-or-equal to scenario.  I.e., Calling `New MyNumRange(32000, Nothing)` *should* equate (after calling `MyNumRange`'s overridden `ToString` method) to `32000 ~` (note the trailing space, and assume `~` is the delimiter).

Except, calling `New MyNumRange(32000, Nothing)` doesn't jump to the constructor with a signature of `New(UInt16?, UInt16?)`, but to `New(UInt16?, Boolean)` instead.  This causes `NumericRange` to process the number `32000` as a single, specific value, not the open-ended range.

My question is, how can I use the constructors as I have them defined above in such a way that I can pass a `Nothing` value to the second argument of the `New(UInt16?, UInt16?)` constructor, it gets translated into `Nothing`, and `num2.HasValue`, if called from within the constructor, would report `False`?

Do I need to rethink how I have my constructors set up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default constructor of `Nullable<T>` can be utilized. When called as `new Nullable<UInt16>()`, it will act as a nullable with no value. In VB terms, you should be able to do `New Nullable(of UInt16)()`.

Comment: This works.  It's not intuitive, but it works.  I can't find another way to write out and overload my constructors to properly articulate the number of ways my object/class can be initialized.  But, that's why I have a `FromString` function, too.

Answer (score 1):

`DirectCast(Nothing, UInt16?)` will give you the value you want to pass in, but doing so produces a compiler error:

```
Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' can be called without a narrowing conversion:
    'Public Sub New(num As UShort, flag As Boolean)': Argument matching parameter 'num' narrows from 'Short' to 'UShort'.
    'Public Sub New(num As UShort, flag As Boolean)': Argument matching parameter 'flag' narrows from 'UShort?' to 'Boolean'.
    'Public Sub New(num1 As UShort?, num2 As UShort?)': Argument matching parameter 'num1' narrows from 'Short' to 'UShort?'.
```

However, it works fine if you use pass in an explicitly-typed value:

```
Dim num1 As UInt16? = 32000S
Dim r = New MyNumRange(num1, DirectCast(Nothing, UInt16?))
```

Comment: This also works, and is equally not intuitive from the way VB does things.  I'll have to note both methods in the XML documentation for these constructors.  Thanks!